# Gabor Filter on on each Superpixel

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, gabor-filter, superpixels

I am working on superpixel for the feature extraction. I have successfully applied superpixel function to the image.

```
A = imread('kobi.png');
[L,N] = superpixels(A,5);
figure
BW = boundarymask(L);
figure;imshow(imoverlay(A,BW,'cyan'),'InitialMagnification',67)
```

[image]

Now I want to extract texture feature from each of the segment (i.e. Gabor features).
Anyone please help me to explain how can I apply Gabor features on each superpixel?

**UPDATE:**

```
idx=label2idx(L);
meanColor = zeros(N,3);
[m,n] = size(L);
for  i = 1:N
       meanColor(i,1) = mean(A(idx{i}));
    meanColor(i,2) = mean(A(idx{i}+m*n));
    meanColor(i,3) = mean(A(idx{i}+2*m*n));
end

numColors = 6;
[pidx,cmap] = kmeans(meanColor,numColors,'replicates',2);
cmap = lab2rgb(cmap);
Lout = zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2));
for i = 1:N
    Lout(idx{i}) = pidx(i);
end
imshow(label2rgb(Lout))
```

[image]
How can I have separate variable for each variable

Comment: Apply the filters to the whole image, then collect information from the result within each superpixel.

Comment: after applying filter how i will match the result belong to which superpixel?

Comment: `L` is a label image, and the filter result is an image also. The positions within these correspond. You can use `regionprops` to average filter output per superpixel, for example.

Comment: I have added an update to my question.

Comment: So you already know how to average pixel values per label, that gets you 99% there to do the Gabor features, no? What else are you missing? Please make that explicit. Also, I don't understand the update to your question "How can I have separate variable for each variable". Please clarify that!

Comment: Taking the average of each superpixel gives me the gabor feature of each superpixel? that will just one value, isn't?
The update is about having each superpixel as a different label. Can you please pointout which part of code confusing you?

Comment: I don't understand the question. A separate variable for each variable?

Comment: Aadnan, do you have some more feedback on what you mean with a "separate variable for each variable"? Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Try This. I hope This will solve your problem of extracting each pixel. 
I hope someone will explain about Gabor features.

```
for i=1:size(Lout,1)
    for j=1:size(Lout,2)
        if (Lout (i,j) == 4)
            Patch(i,j)=A(i,j);
        end
    end
end


mask = Patch > 0;
mask = bwareafilt(mask, 1);
% Invert mask and get bounding box.
props = regionprops(mask, 'BoundingBox');
% Crop image.
croppedImage = imcrop(Patch, props.BoundingBox);
figure;imshow(croppedImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the [MATLAB tutorial about Gabor features](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/texture-segmentation-using-gabor-filters.html), I can apply a Gabor filter bank to the 'kobi' image:

```
wavelengthMin = 4/sqrt(2);
wavelength = 2.^(0:4) * wavelengthMin;
deltaTheta = 45;
orientation = 0:deltaTheta:(180-deltaTheta);
g = gabor(wavelength,orientation);

A = imread('kobi.png');
Agray = rgb2gray(A);
gabormag = imgaborfilt(Agray,g);
```

`g` contains, in this case, 20 filter kernels (see the [documentation to `gabor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/gabor.html)). [`imgaborfilt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaborfilt.html) applies each of those kernels (by convolution) to the image `Agray`, a grey-value version of the 'kobi' image. `gabormag` now is a 3D image, with 20 planes, each one the magnitude of the output of one of the Gabor filters.

The Gabor filter response is sometimes taken as the features for each pixel. In the MATLAB tutorial they apply local averaging, meaning that for each pixel, the Gabor features are averages of the filter responses within a small neighborhood. For use with superpixels it makes sense to average the filter responses within each superpixel. Let's repeat your code to get superpixels first:

```
[L,N] = superpixels(A,500);
```

`L` is a labeled image: each pixel has the value corresponding to the ID of a superpixel. These labels start at 1 and are consecutive.

Using [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) we can compute the mean intensity within each labeled region:

```
K = size(gabormag,3);
gaborfeatures = zeros(N,K);
for ii=1:K
   res = regionprops(L,gabormag(:,:,ii),'MeanIntensity');
   gaborfeatures(:,ii) = [res.MeanIntensity]';
end
```

(You can also use `label2idx` and iterate over its output arrays like you did in the edit to your question.)

`gaborfeatures` now contains one row for each superpixel, and one column for each Gabor feature. For example, `gaborfeatures(294,:)` are the Gabor features for the superpixel `L==294`, which is on the dog's nose:

```
>> gaborfeatures(294,:)
ans =
   1.0e+04 *
  Columns 1 through 9
    0.0008    0.0040    0.0171    0.0848    1.0617    0.0009    0.0040    0.0193    0.1304
  Columns 10 through 18
    0.7753    0.0008    0.0040    0.0165    0.0872    1.0672    0.0010    0.0046    0.0208
  Columns 19 through 20
    0.0842    0.6736
```